# Fill flowframe horizontally first

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, flowfram

I just discovered the flowfram package and I'm trying to discover some of its features.

I have a flowfram of four columns with a static frame on the top left corner of my page. (I did this so the static part could be wrapped by a 'multicols' text).

This is my current example code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,final,hyphenatedtitles]{article}

\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Demo for MWE

\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.2cm}
\setlength{\columnwidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\columnsep}
\setlength{\columnwidth}{0.25\columnwidth}

\newstaticframe[1]{\dimexpr 2\columnwidth+\columnsep}{0.28\textheight}{0pt}{0.72\textheight}[widecolumn]

\newflowframe[1]{\columnwidth}{0.70\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe[1]{\columnwidth}{0.70\textheight}{\dimexpr \columnwidth+\columnsep}{0pt}
\newflowframe[1]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr 2\columnwidth+2\columnsep}{0pt}
\newflowframe[1]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr 3\columnwidth+3\columnsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% default for multicols
\begin{staticcontents*}{widecolumn}
\lipsum[10]
\end{staticcontents*}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: current sample]

What I want to achieve is similar with what the multicols env do. I want to place two frames, one below the other, where they are both filled horizontally before using more vertical space. But I don't want to have them placed statically in a page height.

Like the image below (made with gimp).

[image: expected result]

The red brackets indicate the two sections of text and the green squares shows the static sections of text that should be wrapped with text.

What I've tried to do was to use vertically stacked flowframes containing multicols environment, but this way I lose the text wrapping which the columns made with flowfram provide me.

Another attempt was to create a flowfram inside another flowframe (which i didn't even got it to work).

Is this possible to achieve? Thank you very much.

Comment: You would need 8 flowframes and 2 staticframes, but you have to know how big to make them ahead of time.  Multicols can compute how much room is needed and adjust the column lenghts to fit.

Comment: You could use flowframe to create 2 wide columns then use multicol to subdivide them into two more each, but that won't align all 4.

Comment: If you want to dynamically adjust the size of the columns, you might be better off using TikZ (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304722/multicols-inside-tcolorbox-breaks-page-before-long-multicols-and-doesnt-listen)

Comment: I know I could use 2 static frames and lock everything on its place, but i this is not my goal. About the 2 flowframe with multicols it would be difficult to align the text for each section. I'll take look into TikZ. Thank you