# Double column document with tcolorbox that spans both columns

Tags: boxes, two-column, tcolorbox

I am trying to make a document so that a colorbox, in a double column book document, spans both of the columns nad I do not know what to do. Here is my test.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,twocolumn,openany]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{monstertan}{HTML}{FDF1DC}  %e.g. used for newer monsterblock
\definecolor{iron}{HTML}{CBCDCD}    %e.g. used for older monsterbox
\definecolor{undergold}{HTML}{C9AD6A}   % e.g. used for titlerules
\definecolor{uppergold}{HTML}{B89A67}   %e.g. used for pagenumbers and footer
\definecolor{brass}{HTML}{B5A642}
\definecolor{copper}{HTML}{b87333}
\definecolor{black}{HTML}{000000}

\DeclareTColorBox{paperbox}{O{} m O{iron}}{
    frame hidden,
    boxrule=0pt,
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    before skip=11pt plus 1pt,
    toptitle=3mm,
    boxsep=0.25ex,
    left=8pt,
    right=8pt,
    fonttitle=\fontfamily{fosj}\selectfont\scshape\bfseries\color{brass},
    fontupper=\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont,
    title=#2,
    arc=0mm,
    parbox = false,
    borderline north={1pt}{-0.5pt}{brown},
    borderline south={1pt}{-0.5pt}{brown},
    colback=#3,
    colframe=#3,
    colbacktitle=#3,
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-3.5pt}{-0.5pt}{0.4mm}{black!60!white},
    overlay={
        \fill [fill=brown] (frame.south west) -- ++(7pt,0) -- ++(0,-5pt) -- cycle;
        \fill [fill=brown] (frame.north west) -- ++(7pt,0) -- ++(0,5pt) -- cycle;
        \fill [fill=brown] (frame.north east) -- ++(-7pt,0) -- ++(0,5pt) -- cycle;
        \fill [fill=brown] (frame.south east) -- ++(-7pt,0) -- ++(0,-5pt) -- cycle;
    },
    after={\vspace{10pt plus 1pt}\noindent},
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*
\begin{paperbox}[width=200px]{lipsum}
\lipsum
\end{paperbox}
\end{document}
```

How do I go about doing it?

Comment: Would temporarily switching to one column be an option? `\begin{onecolumn}
\begin{paperbox}{lipsum}
\lipsum
\end{paperbox}
\end{onecolumn}`

Comment: \onecolumn and \twocolumn cause a page break.  You could use multicol instead,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One alternative to `multicol` could be `cuted`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{cuted,tcolorbox,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{strip}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=A tcolorbox]
    \lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{strip}
\lipsum[3-6]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a multicol solution.  See also [multicols inside tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304722/multicols-inside-tcolorbox-breaks-page-before-long-multicols-and-doesnt-listen)

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\definecolor{monstertan}{HTML}{FDF1DC}  %e.g. used for newer monsterblock
\definecolor{iron}{HTML}{CBCDCD}    %e.g. used for older monsterbox
\definecolor{undergold}{HTML}{C9AD6A}   % e.g. used for titlerules
\definecolor{uppergold}{HTML}{B89A67}   %e.g. used for pagenumbers and footer
\definecolor{brass}{HTML}{B5A642}
\definecolor{copper}{HTML}{b87333}
\definecolor{black}{HTML}{000000}

\DeclareTColorBox{paperbox}{O{} m O{iron}}{
    frame hidden,
    boxrule=0pt,
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    before skip=11pt plus 1pt,
    toptitle=3mm,
    boxsep=0.25ex,
    left=8pt,
    right=8pt,
    fonttitle=\fontfamily{fosj}\selectfont\scshape\bfseries\color{brass},
    fontupper=\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont,
    title=#2,
    arc=0mm,
    parbox = false,
    borderline north={1pt}{-0.5pt}{brown},
    borderline south={1pt}{-0.5pt}{brown},
    colback=#3,
    colframe=#3,
    colbacktitle=#3,
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-3.5pt}{-0.5pt}{0.4mm}{black!60!white},
    overlay={
        \fill [fill=brown] (frame.south west) -- ++(7pt,0) -- ++(0,-5pt) -- cycle;
        \fill [fill=brown] (frame.north west) -- ++(7pt,0) -- ++(0,5pt) -- cycle;
        \fill [fill=brown] (frame.north east) -- ++(-7pt,0) -- ++(0,5pt) -- cycle;
        \fill [fill=brown] (frame.south east) -- ++(-7pt,0) -- ++(0,-5pt) -- cycle;
    },
    after={\vspace{10pt plus 1pt}\noindent},
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{multicols}
\begin{paperbox}{lipsum}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{paperbox}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In previous solutions, the text flows from left column to right column before tcolorbox and it continues before the tcolorbox from left to right column. I've nothing to add if this is the desired behaviour. But if you prefer text flowing on left column before and after the tcolorbox and later going to right column, following code shows a partial (manual) solution.

It uses `tcolorbox` `magazine` and `tcbraster` libraries and also `multicol` instead of `twocolumn` option.

You should know which part of the text is going to be on the interrupted page and decide how long will be the four text fragments. I decide their sizes by trial and error tests. All this text will be inserted in `mybox` environment which will fragment it and produce 6 fragments. Later on all these fragments are placed on our paper. The page with the tcolorbox is composed with a `tcbraster` environment where 4 central fragments are placed.

To distinguish between `fragmented` text and regular one, I've added a watermark number behind each fragment.

I must say that the final alignment is not perfect, but I don't know how to improve it.

The final composition looks like:

[image]

And a detail for the tcolorbox page is:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    blanker,
    notitle,
    colback=green!7,
    break at=\pagegoal-\pagetotal-8mm/5cm/10.5cm/5cm/10.5cm/0pt,
    reset box array,
    store to box array,
    watermark text=\arabic{tcbbreakpart},
    width=\linewidth,
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[4-9]
\end{mybox}
\consumetcboxarray{1}{blanker,before=\par\vfill\noindent}
\end{multicols}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2, raster valign=top]
\tcbitem[blanker]\consumeboxarray{2}
\tcbitem[blanker]\consumeboxarray{4}
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2, title=A tcolorbox, rounded corners, colframe=black, colback=pink, size=normal]
\lipsum[2]
\tcbitem[blanker]\consumeboxarray{3}
\tcbitem[blanker]\consumeboxarray{5}
\end{tcbitemize}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\consumetcboxarray{6}{blanker,before=\par\vfill\noindent}
\lipsum[10-13]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```