# formatting using tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to use the format shown in a photo that I found on a website. However, I am unable to download it because the website is in Chinese. Can you help me with obtaining the format or finding an alternative source?[image]
website of the code : https://www-latexstudio-net.translate.goog/index/details/index/mid/2452?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Comment: please , could you do it for me, I am new in latex

Comment: What happens at the bottom of a page?  In other words, is it breakable (which tcolorbox is good at, although see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304722/multicols-inside-tcolorbox-breaks-page-before-long-multicols-and-doesnt-listen/305372?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C26.9710#305372)?  But you would still need to crate a new shape (node), which is not easy at all.

Answer (score 3):

Some code which can be used to provide something quite similar to these boxes is proposed in [Package pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tcb/O' and I am going to ignore it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/689071/1952). I've adapted this code to provide what is seen here: boxes with sharp corners, consecutive enumeration, title adjusted to the left upper corner and the option to do breakable boxes with broken left arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum,lmodern}

\newcounter{myboxcounter}

\tcbset{
    myboxstyle/.style={
        enhanced, breakable,
        sharp corners,
        left skip=8mm,
        attach boxed title to top left={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
        boxed title style={colframe=#1!40, height=6mm, bean arc, boxrule=1pt},
        colback=#1!10, colframe=#1!30, boxrule=1pt,
        coltitle=black, colbacktitle=#1!10,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        underlay boxed title={%
            \node[circle, fill=#1!10, draw=#1!40, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=6mm, line width=1pt, font=\bfseries] (boxnumber) at ([xshift=-6mm]title.west) {\thetcbcounter};
        },
        underlay unbroken={%
            \draw[#1!40, line width=1pt] (title.west)--(boxnumber);
            \draw[#1!40, -{stealth}, line width=1pt] (boxnumber)--(boxnumber|-frame.south);
        },
        underlay first={%
            \draw[#1!40, line width=1pt] (title.west)--(boxnumber);
            \draw[#1!40, line width=1pt] (boxnumber)--(boxnumber|-frame.south);
        },
        underlay middle={%
            \draw[#1!40, line width=1pt] (boxnumber|-frame.north)--(boxnumber|-frame.south);
        },
        underlay last={%
            \draw[#1!40, -{stealth}, line width=1pt] (boxnumber|-frame.north)--(boxnumber|-frame.south);
        },
    }
}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=myboxcounter]{example}[2][]{%
    myboxstyle=#2, title=Example, #1
}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=myboxcounter]{solution}[2][]{%
    myboxstyle=#2, title=Solution, #1
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{example}{blue}
    \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{example}

\begin{solution}{red}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{solution}

\begin{example}{green}
    \lipsum[3-7]
\end{example}

\begin{solution}{yellow}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]