# Package pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tcb/O' and I am going to ignore it

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors, tcolorbox, pgfkeys

When I am compiling this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum,lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,listings,breakable,poster}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{example}[2]{%
    enhanced,
    left skip=1cm,attach boxed title to top text left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-2mm},
    boxed title style={colframe=#1!40!white,arc=3mm},
    colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!10!white,coltitle=black,colbacktitle=#1!10!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Example,
    underlay boxed title={
        \node [circle,fill=#1!10!white,draw=#1!40!white,inner sep=1pt] (A) at ($(title.west) + (-8mm,0)$){\thetcbcounter};
        \draw[#1!40!white,-{stealth}] (title.west) -- (A) --  (frame.south west-|A);},
        #2
}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{sol}[2]
{%
    enhanced,
    left skip=1cm,attach boxed title to top text left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-2mm},
    boxed title style={colframe=#1!40!white,arc=3mm},
    colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!10!white,coltitle=black,colbacktitle=#1!10!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Solution,
    underlay boxed title={
        \node [circle,fill=#1!10!white,draw=#1!40!white,inner sep=1pt] (A) at ($(title.west) + (-8mm,0)$){\thetcbcounter};
        \draw[#1!40!white,-{stealth}] (title.west) -- (A) --  (frame.south west-|A);},
        #2
}



\begin{document}


\begin{example}{blue}
    Our Example
\end{example}


\begin{sol}{red}
    here is the solution
\end{sol}

\end{document}
```

Throw this error:

```
Package pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tcb/O' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Package pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tcb/h' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use

```
\begin{example}{blue}
    Our Example
\end{example}
```

your definition should have one mandatory argument, not two:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum,lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,listings,breakable,poster}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{example}[1]{%
    enhanced,
    left skip=1cm,attach boxed title to top text left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-2mm},
    boxed title style={colframe=#1!40!white,arc=3mm},
    colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!10!white,coltitle=black,colbacktitle=#1!10!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Example,
    underlay boxed title={
        \node [circle,fill=#1!10!white,draw=#1!40!white,inner sep=1pt] (A) at ($(title.west) + (-8mm,0)$){\thetcbcounter};
        \draw[#1!40!white,-{stealth}] (title.west) -- (A) --  (frame.south west-|A);},
%        #2
}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{sol}[1]
{%
    enhanced,
    left skip=1cm,attach boxed title to top text left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-2mm},
    boxed title style={colframe=#1!40!white,arc=3mm},
    colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!10!white,coltitle=black,colbacktitle=#1!10!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Solution,
    underlay boxed title={
        \node [circle,fill=#1!10!white,draw=#1!40!white,inner sep=1pt] (A) at ($(title.west) + (-8mm,0)$){\thetcbcounter};
        \draw[#1!40!white,-{stealth}] (title.west) -- (A) --  (frame.south west-|A);},
%        #2
}



\begin{document}


\begin{example}{blue}
    Our Example
\end{example}


\begin{sol}{red}
    here is the solution
\end{sol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Sancarter_is_at_topansw Excellent answer (+1)! If I have a long question and or answer that span on nexr page, I make the tcolorboxes brekables. The different color is conserved but the left arrow dont span on the following page. Can we solve this aspect?

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro It would be easier to solve if you would ask a new question including a MWE which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the environments with two arguments and the second one should be a set of additional options, according to the code you wrote.

However, the call has just one argument in braces, but TeX will look for another one (ignoring spaces or endlines), so it finds `O`.

Solution:

```
\begin{example}{blue}{}
...
\end{example}
\begin{sol}{red}{}
...
\end{sol}
```

or remove the second argument altogether from the definitions.