# Question answer with left arrow dont spanning on the following page

Tags: tcolorbox

I make reference at this question:
[Package pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tcb/O' and I am going to ignore it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689071/package-pgfkeys-i-do-not-know-the-key-tcb-o-and-i-am-going-to-ignore-it/689073?noredirect=1#comment1709893_689073)
and to accepted answer.
If the text of question and or of the answer span on the next page, like here:

[image]

the left arrow dont span on the next page (with both tcoloboxes breckables).
Can we solve this problem?

Comment: The Ignasi answer is perfect for me. The arrow span over multiple page if needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `breakable` boxes, and adjust the lateral line to the corresponding kind of box: unbreak, first, middel or last.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum,lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,listings,breakable,poster}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{example}[2]{%
    enhanced, breakable,
    left skip=1cm,attach boxed title to top text left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-2mm},
    boxed title style={colframe=#1!40!white,arc=3mm},
    colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!10!white,coltitle=black,colbacktitle=#1!10!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Example,
    underlay boxed title={
        \node [circle,fill=#1!10!white,draw=#1!40!white,inner sep=1pt] (A) at ($(title.west) + (-8mm,0)$){\thetcbcounter};
     },
     underlay unbroken={
        \draw[#1!40!white,-{stealth}] (title.west) -- (A) --  (frame.south west-|A);},
     underlay first={
        \draw[#1!40!white] (title.west) -- (A) --  (frame.south west-|A);},
     underlay middle={
        \draw[#1!40!white] (frame.north west-|A) --  (frame.south west-|A);},
     underlay last={
        \draw[#1!40!white,-{stealth}] (frame.north west-|A) --  (frame.south west-|A);},
        #2
}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{sol}[2]
{%
    enhanced, breakable,
    left skip=1cm,attach boxed title to top text left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-2mm},
    boxed title style={colframe=#1!40!white,arc=3mm},
    colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!10!white,coltitle=black,colbacktitle=#1!10!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Solution,
    underlay boxed title={
        \node [circle,fill=#1!10!white,draw=#1!40!white,inner sep=1pt] (A) at ($(title.west) + (-8mm,0)$){\thetcbcounter};
     },
     underlay unbroken={
        \draw[#1!40!white,-{stealth}] (title.west) -- (A) --  (frame.south west-|A);},
     underlay first={
        \draw[#1!40!white] (title.west) -- (A) --  (frame.south west-|A);},
     underlay middle={
        \draw[#1!40!white] (frame.north west-|A) --  (frame.south west-|A);},
     underlay last={
        \draw[#1!40!white,-{stealth}] (frame.north west-|A) --  (frame.south west-|A);},
        #2
}



\begin{document}


\begin{example}{blue}{}
    Our Example
    
    \lipsum[1-20]
\end{example}


\begin{sol}{red}{}
    here is the solution
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{sol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very well! Ottimo. Perfetto.