# tcolorbox inside multicol with figures: box shifted to next column

Tags: floats, multicol, tcolorbox

Why doesn't `tcolorbox` put the text just below the figure?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{Figure}
 \includegraphics[width=9.014cm]{explicit.png}
\end{Figure}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: some more information about this problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223398/1952

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does it if you uses `report` class `twocolumn` option instead of `multicol` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{Figure}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{Figure}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes I work with large equations and big pictures, can I break 'twocolumns' eventually?

Comment: Yes. You can use figure*. Now I don't remember the equivalent for equations.