# multicolumn unexpected behavior

Tags: tcolorbox, multicolumn, multicol

I ran into a problem while writing a math-cheatsheet template. The template should feature a multicolumn setup with very small margins and a few simple theorem environments using the `tcolorbox` package. I am using the starred multicols environment `multicols*` with 4 columns in addition to the `\raggedcolumns` command so that the columns are not forced to equal height.

My problem is, that I get some large (seemingly) random chunks of whitespace. I don't get what could cause something like that. Here is an example:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, there is a large whitespace after the fourth section which I don't want. Additionally, if you look at the second (or fifth) definition, you can see that I have enabled the `breakable` property for my definition tcbtheorem. There is quite some space after the fourth section header so most of the definition environment should fit.

Here is the code to the screenshot (along with some more blindtext that produces other whitespace chunks):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[landscape,margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  frame hidden,
  boxrule=0pt,
  sharp corners,
  detach title,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
  before upper*={\tcbtitle},
  terminator sign colon,
  top=1mm,
  left=0mm,
  right=0mm,
  bottom=1mm,
  coltitle=black,
  colback=gray!10,
  borderline north={0.5pt}{0pt}{black},
  borderline south={0.5pt}{0pt}{black},
}

\newtcbtheorem[]{definition}{Definition}{}{def}

\setlength\parindent{0mm}
\raggedcolumns

\begin{document}  
\begin{multicols*}{4}
  
\section{Section}
\blindtext

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section}

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\section{Section}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section}

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\section{Section}
\blindtext

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section}

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\section{Section}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section}
\blindtext

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section}

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\section{Section}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section}

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "...there is no automatic breakability for a tcolorbox inside a multicols environment.".  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223398/161015

Comment: Thank you! Manually breaking every tcbtheorem environment doesn't seem like a very pleasant experience. Seems like the ```mdframed``` package doesn't work as well. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea. `tcolorbox` doesn't break boxes inside a multicolumn environment, but you can construct a narrow document (where `tcolorbox` can work) and organize resulting pages over another document with `pdfpages` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[paperwidth=74.25mm, paperheight=210mm, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  frame hidden,
  boxrule=0pt,
  sharp corners,
  detach title,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
  before upper*={\tcbtitle},
  terminator sign colon,
  top=1mm,
  left=0mm,
  right=0mm,
  bottom=1mm,
  coltitle=black,
  colback=gray!10,
  borderline north={0.5pt}{0pt}{black},
  borderline south={0.5pt}{0pt}{black},
}

\newtcbtheorem[]{definition}{Definition}{}{def}

\setlength\parindent{0mm}
\raggedcolumns

\begin{document}  
%\begin{multicols*}{4}
  
\section{Section}
\blindtext

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section}

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\section{Section}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section}

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\section{Section}
\blindtext

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section}

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\section{Section}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section}
\blindtext

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section}

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

\section{Section}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section}

\begin{definition}{}{}
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
\end{definition}

%\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

This document produces one column narrow page

[image]

If this document is called, let's say 631320.pdf, it's possible to arrange these pages like a multicolum page with

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x4,landscape]{631320}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like

[image]

Comment: Nice! But please add the meaning of `631320`.

Comment: @Simon Dispa. You're right. Now it's explained.

Comment: Very interesting and creative idea, thank you very much!