# Having trouble with custom box not floating to top of page correctly

Tags: vertical-alignment, tcolorbox, multicol

I found a template which I am using to create some notes inside custom defined textboxes using multicols, however, I'm having a problem with getting some of them to float properly. It's very inconsistent; some boxes will float to the bottom of the page, leaving the section/subsections to fill the space, and sometimes they will work perfectly fine. I'm not sure how to fix this as I am relatively new to LaTeX debugging and I'm working with a template which I didn't make, so I don't know how it works. Here is an example of it not working properly, in the second column. The table of contents in the first column appears to be too widely spaced out; when I was initially editing it the spacing was not this wide.
[image]

This image shows a more proper output:
[image: Image 2]

For a minimal functioning example I can give the main.tex and template code, as well as a sample textbox to run it with.

Template

```
\usepackage[default]{raleway}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{customcolor}{HTML}{696EA8} 
\definecolor{alert}{HTML}{CD5C5C}
\definecolor{w3schools}{HTML}{4CAF50}
\definecolor{subbox}{gray}{0.60}
\definecolor{codecolor}{HTML}{FFC300} 
\definecolor{mDarkTeal}{HTML}{23373b}
\colorlet{beamerboxbg}{black!2}
\colorlet{beamerboxfg}{mDarkTeal}
\definecolor{mDarkBrown}{HTML}{604c38}
\definecolor{mDarkTeal}{HTML}{23373b}
\definecolor{mLightBrown}{HTML}{EB811B}
\definecolor{mLightGreen}{HTML}{14B03D}
\definecolor{alertTextBox}{HTML}{A8696E}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{most,listingsutf8,minted}

\tcbset{tcbox width=auto,left=1mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
right=1mm,boxsep=1mm,middle=1pt}

\newenvironment{mycolorbox}[2]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[grow to left by=-1em,grow to right by=-1em,capture=minipage,fonttitle=\large\bfseries, enhanced jigsaw,boxsep=1mm,colback=#1!30!white,on line,tcbox width=auto,
arc=2pt,outer arc=2pt, 
toptitle=0mm,colframe=#1,opacityback=0.7,nobeforeafter,title=#2]%
}{\end{tcolorbox}\\[0.2em]}

\newenvironment{textbox}[1]{\begin{mycolorbox}{customcolor}{#1}}{\end{mycolorbox}}

\newcommand{\bgupper}[3]{\colorbox{#1}{\color{#2}\huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#3}}}
\newcommand{\bg}[3]{\colorbox{#1}{\bfseries\color{#2}#3}}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[2]{{\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}}~\dotfill{}~{#2}\\}

\newcommand{\sep}{{\scriptsize~\faCircle{ }~}}


\newcommand{\bggreen}[1]{\medskip\bgupper{w3schools}{black}{#1}\\[0.5em]}
\newcommand{\green}[1]{\smallskip\bg{w3schools}{white}{#1}\\}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\smallskip\bg{alert}{white}{#1}\\}
\newcommand{\alert}[1]{\red{#1}\\}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newenvironment{myblock}[1]{%
    \tcolorbox[capture=minipage,fonttitle=\small\bfseries\color{mDarkTeal}, enhanced jigsaw,boxsep=1mm,colback=black!10,breakable,noparskip,
    on line,tcbox width=auto,left=0.3em,top=1mm, toptitle=0mm,
    colframe=black!20, arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
    opacityback=0.7,nobeforeafter,title=#1]}%
    {\endtcolorbox}

\newcommand{\mygraphics}[2][]{%
\tcbox[enhanced,boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,
right=0pt,boxrule=0.4pt,drop fuzzy shadow,clip upper,
colback=black!75!white,toptitle=2pt,bottomtitle=2pt,nobeforeafter,
center title,fonttitle=\small\sffamily,title=\detokenize{#2}]%
{\includegraphics[width=\the\dimexpr(\linewidth-4mm)\relax]{#2}}%
}
```

Main tex file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%-------------------------

\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\date{\today}
\input{template.tex}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\small
\begin{multicols}{3}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\scriptsize
\tableofcontents

%-----------------------------------------------------

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{textbox}{Textbox}

Text can go here; red and green boxes may be made with \red and \green respectively. 
Feel free to add more text and sections/subsections as needed.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sagittis dolor at nulla rutrum, a rhoncus ex dapibus. Quisque gravida quam id est suscipit rutrum. In aliquam nibh diam, tempor semper tortor vestibulum at. Sed lobortis lacus quis velit feugiat iaculis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur vitae laoreet ipsum. Sed et lacus hendrerit, auctor ante consectetur, fermentum magna. Aenean eu est diam. Proin tempor facilisis mi quis tempor. Nullam interdum ornare rutrum. Ut posuere hendrerit neque. Curabitur cursus placerat est id vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; 

\end{textbox}

%---------------------------------------------

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason is that LaTeX does not want to break those boxes and wants to fill the page. So the space is evenly distributed between there. For me, I would adjust the contents manually.

Comment: `tcolorbox` can not break pages inside a multicolumn environment. But this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/631391/1952 could help

Comment: @Ignasi thank you! I just tried that out, it did fix the problem I was having. If you'd like to post it as an answer I can accept it.